# transition ease from bottom to top?

Tags: css

How can i make the ease out go all the way from bottom to top on the menu button hover?

http://jsfiddle.net/grafikfabriken/VT4r4/2/

```
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
height:45px;
border-top: 4px solid #FC7600;
margin-top: -4px;
background: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/2925mxg.jpg") repeat-x  0 49px #666666;
transition:  0.5s ease-out 0s;
```

Comment: Can you please explain the desired outcome a little better?

Comment: Yeah, if you look at my fiddle. When you hover the menu the background img is falling from top to bottom and stops almost directly. I want the background image should do the opposite. Slide in from the bottom all the way to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle you define the background-image on hover. Just set a the position of that background-image negative.

Instead of 49px set it to -49px.

`background: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/2925mxg.jpg") repeat-x  0 -49px #666666;`